# i wonder how to make hashmap [java multi chat room]

Tags: java, tcp

I want to make result like

```
{38={mother, father}, 39={son}}
```

But the result is like

```
server={38={son, father, mother}, 39={son, father, mother}}
client={son, father, mother}
```

So anyone can make like this

```
server={38={mother, father}, 39={son}}
```

My code is the following

```
HashMap<String, DataOutputStream> clients;
HashMap<String, Object> server;

nick_name = input.readUTF();
roomnumber= input.readUTF();
if (server.containsKey(roomnumber)){
    clients.put(nick_name, output);
}
else {
    clients.put(nick_name, output);
    server.put(roomnumber,clients);
}
```

Comment: For better help provide [MCVE] (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org))

Comment: Also don't post text/code as image/link ([more info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)). Use [edit] option to correct your post. You should be able to copy-paste that results as text and place it in the question directly.

Comment: i'm sorry for i link the image i'll edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using always the same clients `HashMap` no matter what the room is, you need to create the map dynamically for each new room.

You don't need to declare the `client` variable before the `if` statement, instead you can declare the variable when you need it (in this case in the `if` and `else`).

```
if (server.containsKey(roomnumber)) {
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawTypes" })
    HashMap<String, DataOutputStream> clients =
            (HashMap<String, DataOutputStream>) server.get(roomnumber);
    clients.put(nick_name, output);
} else {
    HashMap<String, Object> clients = new HashMap<>();
    clients.put(nick_name, output);
    server.put(roomnumber,clients);
}
```

Here when `server.containsKey(roomnumber)` is `true` the room already has been added, so you obtain that `HashMap` with `server.get()` and add the client, by the other hand if the condition is not met, you create a new `HashMap`, add the client and then add that room to the server.